# DSolve bvlim error due to Boundary condition

Tags: differential-equations, homework

I am solving an Ode using Mathematica:
$$-p\alpha x^{p-1}=m\ddot{x},\quad x(0)=x_0,\quad x'(0)=x''(0)=0,\quad x(t_1)=0.$$
And I have $p\alpha>0$, all $x$ and $t$ are positive. I want to figure out $t_1$.

This is my code:

```
DSolve[
  {(-p α/m) x[t]^(p - 1) == x''[t],
   x[0] == x0, x'[0] == 0, x''[0] == 0, x[t1] == 0},
  x[t], t, 
  Assumptions -> p α > 0 && p > 0 && m > 0 && t1 > 0 && x0 > 0
]
```

And the error message is

> DSolve: General solution contains implicit solutions. In the boundary value problem, these solutions will be ignored, so some of the solutions will be lost.

How can I do?

Comment: For **second** order diff equation `DSolve` can solve with only `2` initial/boundary condition.

Comment: Thank you! So which 2 of the initial conditions should I choose?

Comment: x''[0] is already given by the equation and can not be specified independently. But your problem is the term  x[t]^(p - 1). Depending on p you can get many widely different solutions. You should set the exponent to a fixed value.

Comment: But p is an important factor in this problem. I’m afraid I can’t make it fixed.